# NG-Spice / Macspice - plot source current?

Tags: spice, ltspice, pspice

It seems that you cannot plot current for circuit elements directly and will therefore have to make use of a series `0V` source to display a graph of current vs time in that branch.

For voltage at say node 1 I have: `plot v(1)`
If my source is labelled `Vin`, then as I have noticed; `plot i(Vin)` does not work.

What is the command for doing this?

Comment: Since you taged this ltspice too, there it is just alt+leftclick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spice 3 derivatives often convert names in netlists to all lowercase, but the command interpreter is usually case sensitive. This confuses many new users; try 'plot i(vin)'. The mixed-case syntax you describe, however, does work okay in MacSpice. This example:

```
Stackexchange MacSpice Example
Vin 1 0 dc 0 sin(0.0 1.0 50)
r1 1 0 1.2K
.control
tran 0.1ms 20ms 0.0 0.5ms
plot i(Vin)
.endc
.end
```

Produces this plot:
[image: Screenshot of plot window in MacSpice]